# use ida python to add a remark when calling a function using register

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I want to add a remark for all non direct function calls.
e.g. say i have

```
mov EAX [functionEP]
call EAX
```

Assuming i have many such calls to various functions, I would like to run the debugger and every time there are calls to such function add a remark which states the real call address/function name so that it will be:

```
mov EAX [functionEP]
call EAX ; functionName
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I use IDA 7.0 and its done automatically although is for `lea`. [See](https://i.imgur.com/fIduLka.png)

Comment: i also use ida 7.0
it is not added for all function calls